# What's the fastest/easiest way to level up your skills?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Basically subj.

The skills and what I found so far is:

- Stamina: just run, sprint, cycle, swim, whatever. Just move and it will grow(not that fast though)
- Shooting: personally I found *shooting range* to be a really fast way to improve your shooting skills
- Strength: fist fighting
- Stealth: performing stealth kills
- Flying: probably just flying, didn't bother about it yet
- Driving: got the most problems here. Playing as a Trevor I can't get past 1.8 or 1.9 bars(which is 36-38%). Drove for hours around and still can't get it any higher
- Lung Capacity: staying underwater for as long as possible can very slowly but surely increase your lung capacity

Am I correct with the ones I know? And what would you recommend for the other ones?

Comment: I found an outside gym thinking I could increase my strength, but I wasn't able to do anything with the weights. I would like to think hunting would improve your shooting.

Comment: Does anything cause your skills to decrease?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to the official GTA 5 Strategy Guide, here is a comprehensive list:

- Stamina: this skill is increased by 1% for every 17 meters (18 yards) ran, every minute swam, every minute cycled. Participating in triathlons is a great way to increase this ability.
- Shooting: this is increased quicker by landing hits on enemies, scoring headshots and successfully completing Shooting Range challenges. This skill is increased by 3% for every Gold challenge completed, 2% for every Silver and 1% for every Bronze. A comment from user79446 says that shooting vehicles, even your own, counts as shooting a valid target to improve shooting.
- Strength: this is increased 1% for every 20 punches. Playing sports (golf, tennis, darts) also increases strength.
- Stealth: this skill is increased by 1% for every 45 meters (49 yards) walked in Stealth Mode and by 1.5% for every two stealth kills.
- Flying: flying for 10 minutes increases this skill by 1%.
  Completing the following training at the Flying School increases this skill by 3% for Gold, 2% for Silver and 1% for Bronze: Training take off, Runway landing, Inverted flight, Knife flight, Flat hatting, Loop the loop, Sky diving, Drop zone.
  Completing the following training at the Flying School increases this skill by 5% for Gold, 3% for Silver and 2% for Bronze: Touch down, Helicopter course.
  Completing the Helicopter speed run training increases the stats by 6%/4%/3%.
- Driving: this skill is increased by 1% for every 10 seconds of wheelie action and an additional 1% for every second spent in the air in a vehicle or four-wheel landing. Performing Stunt Jumps with four-wheel landings gives the greatest boost to this skill.
- Lung Capacity: this stats is increased by 1% for every minute spent underwater.

Comment: `Lung Capacity: this stats is increased by 1% for every minute spent underwater.` Even while you're in a submarine or using a diving suit?

Comment: for Lung Capacity: is it 1 minute of in-game time or a real 1 minute?

Comment: @Novarg I assume it's real time. 1 minute ingame is equivalent to 1 second real time. Spending only 2 real minutes underwater for 100% lung capacity doesn't seem very reasonable.

Comment: @Nolonar: yes, real time

Comment: *Stamina: this skill is increased by 1% for every 17 meters (18 yards) ran, every minute swam, every minute cycled* - so basically running will boost your stamina like gazillion times faster than cycling/swimming?

Comment: @Novarg : there's fatigue while running, though, isn't it?

Comment: @C.B. I think it also exists for cycling and swimming. When you are mashing *X* at least(PS3)

Comment: But stamina still increases while cycling/swimming *even without* mashing X...

Comment: So will getting bronze, silver, gold on the same shooting range challenge get you a 6% increase or only 3%?

Comment: where's the flight school?  is that online?

Comment: @FistOfFury no, it's part of the single player story

Comment: @Nolonar I got a notification of improved Lung Capacity while swimming  in scuba gear.

Comment: Shooting skill increases by firing on cars too. Get a car into a garage, unload all your bullets into it. Close and reopen the garage whenever it catches fire.

There's a mission where you shoot an AK from the back of a car. Keep firing on the enemy cars and your assault rifle skill should be maxed out.

Answer (score 6):

Once you get the hang of tennis, play a few sets with Michael and Trevor. One set seems to raise strength by at least 20%, and it can be done on easy mode. Takes way less time to get strength to 100 this way as opposed to punching people (and running from cops).

Answer (score 4):

#### Special

Skilled by using up your Special gauge (press the left and right stick simultaneously)

#### Stamina

Skilled by using up your Stamina. Simply moving won't do, you need to move *fast*. It shouldn't be too difficult to skill, as long as you mash the `A` button (360) or the `X` button (PS3) while on foot, on a bicycle, or while swimming/diving.

#### Shooting

Skilled by shooting things, this skill will come along naturally.
Fastest way of improving this skill is by visiting the shooting range, just like Michael recommended to Franklin.

#### Strength

Skilled by punching people.
It's possible that visiting gyms can help improve this skill faster than punching everyone.

#### Stealth

Skilled by moving around stealthily. Whether people see you or not, does not seem to matter. Just press the left stick and move around. Apparently, silent takedowns also add to the stealth skill.

#### Flying

Skilled by flying around with planes, helicopters, or even the parachute.
Fastest and easiest way of improving this skill is by visiting the flight school at the Los Santos airport.

#### Driving

According to the ingame description, this is skilled by performing perfect landings (when your land vehicle is airborne) or by doing wheelies.
Based on that, it seems like the easiest and fastest way of improving this skill, is by driving over uneven terrain (offroad) instead of regular roads, whenever possible.

#### Lung Capacity

Skilled by diving (possibly without diving suit).

Answer (score 4):

Stealth : go to the pier with the farris wheel and sneak behind people, kill them with a knife. Cops have a hard time getting out to you and the stealth kills quickly raise your stat.

Answer (score 3):

THE BEST way to upgrade STRENGTH.   Beat up on an unoccupied car with bare hands.  (do not use knife or bat or anything else)  It will only take you about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

For stealth, I put on a movie and walked around in stealth mode until it maxed out. Took about 30-45 minutes. Lung capacity was tedious. I just swam up and down the shore as much as I could. Took about an hour to max that out. Stamina is easy. Get a bike or run around. Also, hooking up with a stripper will increase your stamina. Driving- easy. Flying, go to flight school when it's available. You will max out before the end of the challenges. Shooting, go to the shooting range. Same as flight school.

I'm still working on strength. Takes forever. I played a bunch of golf and punched a lot of people. Still not even half way to being maxed. They should add a gym or MMA competition(cage fighting) to work on strength.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion for driving would be driving close to other cars very fast, so you get near misses.

Answer (score 2):

STEALTH - Find a quite steep hill and stealth down that, you walk a lot faster downhill in stealth, therefore covering more ground in a quicker time, I found this the best way to improve that particular skill.

Answer (score 1):

Stealth

Set your player in stealth mode and tie a piece of string round your left stick and leave it for 30 or 40 mins, come back and Stealth will be 100%

Answer (score 1):

For raising the strength stat (at least as Michael-haven't tried others yet), I managed to max him out with tennis. First I tried the end option (5 games I think) don't really KNOW tennis & assumed (wrongly) that'd be the max play-saw no noticeable change. What you want is SETS (I guess each set is 6 games)...first I played 5 sets (you only have to win 3 full ones) & my stat was 1/2 a bar away from full, so then I played 3 sets (only need win 2). I blew Amanda away/didn't lose a single game & BAM! Maxed out...also don't bother tracking in-game (can't hit down button, but CAN check via start menu), it doesn't boost your stat until game is over (so don't quit thinking nothing's happening-I didn't quit at all, so can't say how that may effect things). Hope that helps!

*As a side-note, I didn't try yet but wonder if you call up one of the others/play a game if BOTH characters stat's will go up or just the one you control at the time-may be worth a look...

Answer (score 1):

Best and easiest way lung capacity get diving gear from submarine or dingy just swim around don't have to come out of the water at all untill full trust me it works pretty fast. flying complete flight school it's faster. shooting shooting range is the fastest. Driving drive in oncoming lane as fast as you can without hitting anything. Strength for Micheal & Trevor play sets in tennis & win. Playing sets seem to work faster to me but i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Stamina - Do triathlons. Online, run or cycle to get around.

Shooting - Get police on you and get headshots.

Strength - Stomp the roof of an occupied bus.

Stealth - Go into stealth mode, place your controller upside-down on the ground so that the
          left stick moves your character and go AFK. Come back in half an hour.

Flying - Flight School. Online, Fly to get around. Helicopters can be found easily or can be 
         called in from Merryweather.

Driving - Get a motorcycle and wheelie in the middle of the oncoming lane on a moterway at 
          top-speed. Do the same stunt jumps for a while.

Lung Cap. - Get diving gear and swim underwater for a while. Online, Swim around underwater
            although you need to come back up for air.

*Done this and got all my characters (including Online) stats maxed in one day.*

Answer (score 1):

The FASTEST way to increase strength in UNDER AN HOUR, is get on top of a bus, and using the attack button, stomp the crap out of the roof, even when it's speeding down the road.  Buses are easy to stay on top of.  Punching is a waste of time, believe me.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I would add is that strength is a lot easier to raise by punching cows.  You don't get the cops after you making it take less time.  Took me about an hour on Franklin (he starts with the lowest strength)

Comment: can you please make this easier to understand?

Answer (score 1):

To train your strength, and mainly with Franklin, standing on a driving bus and kick, really works!(Can be mostly found in the area of Franklin's first house) Very fast too. The rest (Michael and Trevor) could also play Tennis to improve it fast. For Shooting go to the shooting range. For Stamina running and riding a bicycle. For Lung capacity for Michael you can do Yoga (goes fast) for the rest (Franklin and Trevor) just go diving and get up each time you're out of breath. Driving speaks for itself, drive fast and close past other cars and it will be full within an hour or so.

These all work and are the best ways to do it!

Answer (score 1):

Lung Capacity.

Since no one else mentioned this, your lung capacity actually increases when you're underwater while using a scuba mask. So if you have the sonar collections  dock purchased and started the Strangers and Freaks mission to collect the submarine parts, there will be a dinghy at the dock. Just hop in the dinghy go out to sea a bit and jump out. Your character should automatically put on the mask so just dive under the water and swim around till it maxes out. You can still do this after you've found all the sub parts, and maybe even before getting the mission if you just grab any dinghy but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

For flying I just did the flying school.

For stealth just crouch tie a hair band around the analog sticks and just wait for 90 min. Many go see a movie like "gravity."

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that strength may increase a bit faster if you do counters with x and then a on the xbox360 as they are about to punch you.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to nonlinear now you can walk underwater if you sprint into it I just did that made my character go into stealth and then ruberbanded my controller to walk forward

Works quite well just make sure you have a grenade or something to kill yourself so you don't have to walk all that way back unless your trying to get your stamina up

Just check back everyonce and a while because you might come back and be stuck on a rock or coral just jump over it continue and watch out for dropoffs

Comment: What's "nonlinear now"?

Answer (score -1):

**Strength:** If you want to train your strength really fast: get on the roof of a (driving!) bus and just kick with your bare feet.
It's harder to find the bus than training your strength on it, trust me.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Trevor Airfield, southwest of his home. With a bike, do wheelies until your drive skills are 100%.

Answer (score -2):

By beating people up. Look around where Franklin lives - the gangsters are great practice.

Comment: Hello and welcome to gaming.stackexchange.com. We appreciate your willingness to help, but in the future please try to improve your wording and elaborate a little more than a one-sentence answer.

Comment: Your answer is lacking. There are 8 skills; are you telling us, beating people up will improve *all of them*? Those gangsters also tend to gang up on you and shoot you to death upon even the slightest provocation, so it's definitely *not* an efficient way to skill strength.

Answer (score -3):

**Strength:** (Online) The best way to increase stat is to just have a buddy to sit inside a car, while you stand on top of it, and keep stomping on the roof  (This will method takes about 10min to max)

**Stealth:**: (Online) The best way to increase this is just to go into stealth mode and walk around. You don't even have to knock anyone out. (But it will take about 40min)